# Ptyhon, how to add a hyphen b/w two words in a given string

Tags: python, regex, python-re

```
test_str = 'S.No   Device Name        Device Family       Device Type           Device Role   IP Address   Location                 Serial No.     Current    Current SMU    Upgrade Failure Reason,'
```

In the above string, need to add hyphen b/w two words,
eg: Device-Name, Device-Family, Device-Type, IP-Address, Serial-No., Current-SMU, Upgrade- Failure-Reason

If I replace with space other places is also replaced with hyphen

```
replacedText = re.sub(r'\S\s\S' , r'\1', test_str)
```

`'\S\s\S'` --> is finding the single space b/w 2 words, but not sure how to replace with hyphen without missing any characters

So, please help me to give with regex solution.

Note: there is multiple space available between Device Name & Device Family & Device Type etc.

Comment: (1) Format code properly. (2) Is there a rule which words should be bound together with a hyphen and which not?

Comment: Do you think you might stretch to typing the whole word "between" instead of the cryptic abbreviation?

Comment: The Rule is hyphen should be replaced where there is a  single space between two words

Comment: 'S.No Device Name Device Family Device Type Device Role IP Address Location Serial No. Current Current SMU Upgrade Failure Reason,’


In the above string, there are multiple spaces before ‘Device’ and after ‘Name’ 
Now I was expecting a hyphen should bee placed has 'Device-Name'

Comment: This pattern `\S\s\S` will also match `@ #` but I think you mean something more precise right? Like `(?<=[a-z]) (?=[A-Z])` https://regex101.com/r/Hiz8AN/1

Comment: yes,  expecting '\S\s\S' should be replaces with '\S-\S'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\w` to find a character. Then make sure this character is not included in the match by using a *positive lookbehind assertion* `(?<=...)` and a *lookahead assertion* `(?=...)`. If you want to learn more about those assertions then read the [documentation of `re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

```
replaced_text = re.sub(r'(?<=\w) (?=\w)', r'-', test_str)
```

You'll get

`S.No   Device-Name        Device-Family       Device-Type           Device-Role   IP-Address   Location                 Serial-No.     Current    Current-SMU    Upgrade-Failure-Reason,`